# Filter GenericForeignKey by list of different model objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to build activity logs by a User or any other model object, to which a user can follow or subscribe to.

These are the models related with logging the activities:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    """
    An activity log : Actor acts on target
    Actor can be a User or a model Object
    """
    actor_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="actor_type")
    actor_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    actor = GenericForeignKey('actor_content_type', 'actor_object_id')
    description = models.TextField()
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="target_type")
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_object_id')


class Follow(models.Model):
    """
    A user can follow any User or model objects.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    follow_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Suppose:

- Thor follows user Loki // User follows User
- Thor follows user Stark // User follows User
- Thor follows project Avenger // User follows Project

And suppose these are activities:

- Nick Fury Created a project "Shield"
- Nick Fury Created a project "Avengers"
- Stark created a project "Mark II"
- Avengers added Vision
- Dr Strange created a project Dormammu

I can get the user *Thor*:

```
thor = User.objects.get(email="thor@gmail.com")
```

And get the list of users/objects followed by *Thor*:

```
thor.follow_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Follow: thor@gmail.com follows loki@gmail.com>, <Follow: thor@gmail.com follows Stark@gmail.com>, <Follow: thor@gmail.com follows Avengers>]>
```

Now to get the list of activities followed by the user Thor, I tried this:

```
q = (Q(actor__in=thor.follow_set.all())| Q(target__in=thor.follow_set.all())

Activity.objects.filter(q)
```

But its throwing an error:

> FieldError: Field 'actor' does not generate an automatic reverse
> relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a
> GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

I can get all the activities for a single object followed by user Thor:

```
followed_last = thor.follow_set.last().follow_object

q = (Q(actor_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(followed_last), actor_object_id=followed_last.id)| Q(target_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(followed_last), target_object_id=followed_last.id))

Activity.objects.filter(q)
<QuerySet [<Activity: Avengers Added vision@gmail.com>, <Activity: nickfury@gmail.om Created Avengers>]>
```

But how can I get all the activities Thor is following from the above activities:

- Nick Fury Created a project "Avengers"
- Stark created a project "Mark II"
- Avengers added Vision

**Update**

Added User model as requested:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[validate_fullname])
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["fullname"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Can you share the user model?

Comment: @bdbd Hi! I have updated and shared the user model.

Answer (score 1):

A `GenericForeignKey` is in simple words a composition of two fields (a foreign key to `ContentType` and a field to store the related primary key) to point to a specific object. Looking at your code:

```
q = (Q(actor__in=thor.follow_set.all())| Q(target__in=thor.follow_set.all())

Activity.objects.filter(q)
```

This kind of filtering does not work with a `GenericForeignKey` basically because if it did, in case one tries to access related attributes Django would have to perform tasks like:

- Make several joins
- Figure out *which* tables to join so as to not get errors

This would be quite complex and have several problems like long query times if there are too many joins, etc.

Also your code is somewhat incorrect as it filters `Activity` objects related to `Follow` objects and not the *followed* object.

To solve your problem you can instead filter on `actor_content_type`, `actor_object_id`, etc. instead:

```
follows = thor.follow_set.all()

filters = [Q(actor_content_type=follow.content_type)
     & Q(actor_object_id=follow.object_id)
     | Q(target_content_type=follow.content_type)
     & Q(target_object_id=follow.object_id) for follow in follows]

Activity.objects.filter(Q(*filters, _connector=Q.OR))
```

Comment: Would it be more performant to use something like `target_object_id__in=[...]`?

Comment: @alias51 but it might be inaccurate since there might be an object from a different table with the same id, matching on the content type is to make sure the results are correct.

Comment: Except you have `content_type` as your first conditional...?